# Чем std::error_code отличается от std::error_condition

Tags: c++, обработка-ошибок

В С++ есть два похожих класса, https://eel.is/c++draft/syserr.errcode

> **error_code** describes an object used to hold error code values, such as those originating from the operating system or other low-level application program interfaces.

и https://eel.is/c++draft/syserr.errcondition

> **error_condition** describes an object used to hold values identifying error conditions.
>
> [Note 1: error_condition values are portable abstractions, while error_code values ([syserr.errcode]) are implementation specific.
> — end note]

Если я хочу использовать их для своих ошибок, какой лучше использовать и почему?

Comment: Привет. Давно тебя не было видно. Для какого рода ошибок планируешь использовать? Выглядит так, что для переносимого кода надо использовать `error_condition`. А `error_code` просто как обёртка над системными ошибками.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ привет, не совсем так, см. ниже)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: для возврата ошибок - только `error_code`. Для проверки ошибок - можно `error_condition`.

Слова про "переносимые абстракции" у `error_condition` могут смутить разработчика. Давайте посмотрим чем отличаются интерфейсы этих классов: у `error_code` есть функция `default_error_condition()` и `operator<<`. В остальном они буквально одинаковые.

Если посмотреть что пишут в интернете, то [вот тут автор оригинальной boost::system::error_code пишет](https://github.com/boostorg/json/issues/585#issuecomment-864620679)

> Functions should never return errors using error_condition, only with error_code. error_condition is only for comparing codes to.
> Функции никогда не должны возвращать error_condition, только error_code. error_condition нужен только для сравнения кодов.

Также есть пара статей по написанию своих кодов для `error_code` и `error_condition`

- https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/07/12/your-own-error-code/
- https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/08/12/your-own-error-condition/

Где говорится то же самое - функции должны возвращать `error_code`, а при проверке надо сравнивать их с `error_condition`.

На практике это должно выглядеть так:

```
// определяем список кодов ошибок
enum class MyErr { OK, PageNotFound, ServerNotFound, Timeout, InvalidArg, Crash, Unavailable };
// категорию ошибок и т.п.
struct MyErrCategory : std::error_category { ... };

// и используем это в функциях
std::error_code foo() {
  if (...) return MyErr::Timeout;
  return MyErr::OK;
}
```

Для проверки ошибок, мы можем просто сравнивать их с кодами выше

```
if (ec == MyErr::Timeout || ec == MyErr::Unavailable) Retry();
if (ec == MyErr::ServerNotFound || ec == MyErr::InvalidArg || ec == MyErr::Crash) Exit();
if (ec == MyErr::PageNotFound) CreateNewPage();
```

но тут видно, что у нас есть некоторые группы условий ошибок (буквально условий равенства), и мы можем сделать табличку

```
         | PageNotFound |ServerNotFound | Timeout | InvalidArg | Crash | Unavailable
TryAgain |              |               |    +    |            |       |      +
Fatal    |              |      +        |         |     +      |   +   |
```

Тогда мы можем сделать коды для этих групп условий равенства ошибок, еще одну `error_category`, и внутри категории задать таблицу  преобразования кодов ошибки в код условия.

```
// определяем список кодов условий ошибок
enum class MyErrCond { OK, TryAgain, Fatal };
// категорию ошибок
struct MyErrCondCategory : std::error_category {
  ...
  bool equivalent(std::error_code ec, int cond) const noexcept {
    switch (static_cast<MyErrCond>(cond)) {
    case MyErrCond::TryAgain:
      return ec == MyErr::Timeout || ec == MyErr::Unavailable;
    case MyErrCond::Fatal:
      return ec == MyErr::ServerNotFound || ec == MyErr::InvalidArg || ec == MyErr::Crash;
    default: return false;
    }
  }
};
```

теперь мы можем упростить проверку ошибок:

```
if (ec == MyErrCond::TryAgain) Retry();
if (ec == MyErrCond::Fatal) Exit();
if (ec == MyErr::PageNotFound) CreateNewPage();
```

тут надо отметить, что `PageNotFound` и `ServerNotFound` не попадают в одно условие, и для `PageNotFound` можно оставить сравнение с кодом ошибки.

Вот именно это подразумевалось под "`error_code` для возврата ошибок, `error_condition` - для проверки ошибок".

Также не стоит возвращать `error_condition`, чтобы избежать ситуации, когда надо преобразовывать ошибки из разных источников.

```
error_code foo();
error_condition bar();

??? foo_bar() {
  error_code ec1 = foo();
  error_condition ec2 = bar();
  return ???;
}
```

Что касается того, почему в стандарте написано про переносимые ошибки - скорей всего, дело в том, что там определен стандартный `enum class errc` с кодами условий ошибок. И так как его значения зафиксированы в стандарте (почти, в стандарте не сказаны конкретные значения, но они начинаются с 1 и так далее), то это переносимый способ сравнивать системные ошибки. Более того, пользовательская функция может вернуть этот `error_condition`, чтобы, например, переслать его по сети на другую машину, где другие системные коды ошибок.
Но если вы определяете свои коды ошибок, они и так будут одинаковые на всех системах, и для своих ошибок точно не надо возвращать `error_condition`.